# Cakephp 3.x Shopping cart Database scheme

Tags: database, cakephp, schema, shopping-cart, cart

I am planning to build a website using cakephp 3.x version, Anybody please suggest me a  flexible database schema for my project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database schema depends on project requirements. 
Just take the conventions of CakePHP pattern then Project built will be easier

Details check [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)